# How to Create Negative Epoch Value in python

Tags: python, epoch

I am trying to create epoch values for a date field using Python. It works great for all the dates after '1970-01-01'. Any date before 1970 doesn't work.

Here is the code I am using:

```
int(time.mktime(time.strptime('1969-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'))) - time.timezone
```

Error:

```
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
```

Is there any alternative way to create negative epoch value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module:

> The functions in this module may not handle dates and times before the epoch or far in the future.

So that's out.  I would suggest using the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) module instead, which can handle dates in  years between 1 and 9999. I'm afraid without knowing your use case we can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Dates that i am trying to deal with ranges from 1900-currentdate.